# What could be wrong with this conditional formatting formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of students in Excel starting at row 7 downwards. Columns AL and AM are for present and absent days respectively. I have this formula to highlight the two attendance cells for any student if their total isn't the same as the total number of course days:

`=AND(CourseDays=ActiveDays,OFFSET($AL$6,ROW()-ROW($AL$6),0)+OFFSET($AM$6,ROW()-ROW($AM$6),0)<>TotalHours)`

- I removed all other rules that could be overriding the format
- CourseDays, ActiveDays, and TotalHours are named ranges
- When I put this formula in a cell in the same row for a student, result is TRUE but the conditional format rule with the same formula doesn't get applied. What could be wrong? Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: So, if instead of your formula you use `=(1=1)`, it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, dear George. It works. I even used `=AND(CourseDays=ActiveDays,1=1)` and it works!

Comment: I don't understand. Does the conditional formatting work with =(1=1)? If yes, then probably your formula has a problem, but you said it returned 'TRUE'. If not, then something's up with the conditional module settings, but you said: "it works". Can you be more specific please?

Comment: It's hard to help when we don't know what is the data your name references refere to. Sample raw data is always helpful when posting a question. On antoher note, you are using locked references to cell AL6 and AM6. If this formula is to be applied accross a number of rows, it will only test it against these two cells. That might be part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you George and Pomul for your responses. Dear George, it is confusing and doesn't make sense at all. This is why I posted the question. Let me rephrase the problem: when I use =1=1, the formatting gets applied. This means there is a problem with the formula. Well, I used the same formula in a cell on row 7, it evaluated to TRUE. The question is: why doesn't the formula work when it's applied as a conditional formatting formula? The purpose of the formula is to add up the two cells in columns AL and AM in any row below row 6 and the total is checked against a value saved in a named range.

Comment: Is it that the Offset function doesn't work as a conditional formatting formula?

Comment: The Offset function didn't work as expected, so I created another formula for cells in columns AL and AM row 7 and below: `=AND(CourseDays=ActiveDays,$AL7+$AM7<>TotalHours)`. Thanks everybody for the effort. I'm still curious whether the Offset function doesn't work properly with conditional formatting.